# Double tap on application to open

Tags: double, tap

I want to open an application with double tap on it, 
can anyone tell how do i implement it.
Any code or suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to expand your question it is too broad. Tell us about the issue in your code, what language you are using and provide your attempt. StackOverflow doesn't provide all the code for you, you are expected to make an effort yourself.

Comment: It might also help to know what operating system and window manager.

Comment: I'm using windows 7 and want to make an app on Android, it should open on double click